# Is there a way to close a geoprocessing operation when the dialog box has been hidden/pushed to the back of the window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.2

Is there a way to close a geoprocessing operation when the dialog box has been hidden/pushed to the back of the windows? I ran a python process as VB Script and when the error message appeared I misclicked. The error popup was hidden behind the attributes table.

I finally terminated ArcMap.

Is there an easier solution?

Comment: I try about three things, 1. Alt+tab find the dialog. 2. task manager switch to application. 3. touch the application window and hit escape.

Comment: These did not work. The dialog is within ArcMap, it does not show up as an application or a process. Esc/Pause/Break... did not do the trick.

Comment: Try minimizing everything (forcing it if you have to), then click on ArcMap. The results window should be there.

Comment: What version are you using?  I don't think I have seen this since 9.x and there @Paul suggestion is what worked for me (I think)

Comment: I recreated it: field calc > input a python script and select the VB Script radio > Click "OK" > Click outside of the error popup. Windows + D to force minimize, then open it back up and I still cannot get past it. ArcMap 10.1 SP1 Build 3143

Comment: I'm trying to recreate it; are you running it from within the attribute table or from the toolbox?

Comment: From the attribute table. Don't waste too much time on it, Paul. I will try not to make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK. So this is still a problem in 10.2.

I replicate this problem by clicking into the map immediately after I click the tool's 'OK' button, and then changing to a different program (explorer, firefox, etc...). It appears that If I right click the map but do not change programs, the dialog box reappears after it finishes  (which could be a while depending on the operation/network issues).

If your geoprocessing dialog box gets clicked/pushed/focused off of the screen, ArcMAP is basically 'frozen.' You cannot click minimize, resize, exit, file, etc.... Windows + M does not work, Windows + D takes you to the desktop but still doesn't help when you re-open ArcMAP and it is the same size, Alt+Space+M does not work.

What works: Right-click the taskbar and 'Cascade' or 'Tiled/Stacked Horizontally/Vertically.' Open another program to help shrink the stacked windows until you can see your dialog box. Hopefully your dialog box is in a good location. Will update if I find another solution. The 2nd image shows the dialog box behind the ArcMap window.

[image: Model Builder Tool]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this has been driving me nuts for years. Perhaps worthy of a bug report to ESRI? It's only a minor annoyance, until the day you haven't saved your MXD and don't know this trick...

Comment: right clicking on the task bar icon worked for me.

Comment: +1 you are a genius.. seriously this has been annoying me so much!!!

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change the Screen Resolution to get ArcMap to be small enough before cascading.

Comment: This still happens on 10.5.1, and this still fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have Windows 11 and lack the cascade option. It happened to me that I work with various monitors while in the office. However, back home, I just have my laptop's screen. In the application I use I can start scripts from a dialog box that is called script tool. If I issued a script tool in the office and the dialog opens in, let's say, my 2nd display, it will open in this "ghost" display once I disconnected the monitor. If the execution goes ok, the dialog will close itself with no other concern but if there is any error, the dialog will not close. This is a modal dialog so my application gets "trapped" and not reachable by any means.
What have worked to me is to change the display scale in the screen configuration (Windows 11 configuration) and set it to a smaller ratio than before. Then the dialog is visible again and I can close it or whatever I want.
In the end I just have to reset the former display scale.
[image]

Hope this is useful to anyone

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when running custom models (but also when running some map server caching GP operations) on 9.3 in Windows 2003, but as other reported the problem may appear even in newer versions of Windows and ArcGIS. What worked for me:

Open Windows Task Manager and then switch to the Applications tab. Right-click the process that is hiding from you and choose Switch to. The window that was hidden should be brought to front and activated.

[image]

Comment: I prefer to comment here instead of a new answer. I did not have an external process (Create_TurnTable) running as in your case but just ArcMap, similar to OP's case. If I right-click on ArcMap and pick Bring To Front, it puts the tool dialog in the front which let you to press Close button.

Answer (score 0):

I have this when I am working with dual screens in the office and the dialog appears on the second screen. I unplug, go home and work off my laptop screen and the dialog is still on the second screen in the ether...

To get around this issue I have to delete my normal.mxt and restart ArcMap. This re-creates the mxt file with the vanilla ArcMap settings, including default GP dialog screen position.

The normal.mxt is in:

> C:\Users\ :::login name::: \AppData\Roaming
>   \ESRI\Desktop10.x\ArcMap\Templates